# Как сделать из RSS полноценный пост WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, rss

Всем привет!
Есть несколько сайтов на WP. Задача сделать вывод постов (новостей) с одного сайта на все остальные. 
Решил подкючить по RSS ленте, но если в посте присутсвуют картинки или видео с ютуб это становится проблемой. 
Есть ли способ сделать из RSS полноценные посты или какие другие способы вы знаете.
Спасибо!

Comment: В вп есть REST API, там из коробки уже есть готовое апи для постов. Просто разберитесь и используйте его)